# How to execute the script inside a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute the code inside a function, Which can be used anywhere within the environment but its not working, and giving the Error.

> But when i am using the same code without any function it's working fine. i don't understand why is not working when trying to execute within a function

**Input Data**

```
Col1
U_a65839_Jan87Apr88
U_b98652_Feb88Apr88_(2).jpg.pdf
V_C56478_mar89Apr89
NaN
Q_d15634_Apr90Apr91
Q_d15634_Apr90Apr91_(3).jpeg.pdf
S_e15336_may91Apr93
NaN
```

**Expected Output:**

```
col2          start_dt     end_Dt
Jan87Apr88    Jan1987      Apr1988
Feb88Apr88    Feb1988      Apr1988
mar89Apr89    mar1989      Apr1989
Apr90Apr91    Apr1990      Apr1991
Apr90Apr91    Apr1990      Apr1991
may91Apr93    may1991      Apr1993
```

**Code I have been using**

```
def newmap(x):
    try:
        df['col2'] = df.col1.str.split("_", expand=True)[2]
        # split first part
        df['start_dt'] = df.File_Path.str[:5]
        # split second part
        df['end_dt'] = df.File_Path.str[5:10]
        # add 19
        df['start_dt'] = df.start_dt.replace({'(\d\d)': r'19\1'}, regex=True)
        df['end_dt'] = df.end_dt.replace({'(\d\d)': r'19\1'}, regex=True)

    except ValueError:
        df['status'] = ValueError


    return df

df = newmap(df)
```

While Running the above code getting the error

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'col1'

Please Suggest.

Comment: In the input data you have 'Col1' and 'col1' in the function.

Comment: @Arkadiusz-    Typing mistake Its Col1

Comment: looks like your input is `Series` not a `DataFrame` so use the `df.str` instead `df.col1.str` and initiat new `df = pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: @BrownBear - Sir using the df.str instead df.col1.str will check and split the value for whole dataframe. Not getting.

Comment: where do you use the input `x`?

Comment: @BrownBear -  x is not being used , I am not much familiar with creating a function, Please Suggest.

Comment: to understand  your problem and suggest something need [reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)